# Why does broom::tidy occasionally return a wrong type of 'estimate' with speedglm?

Tags: r, glm, broom, speedglm

It is documented that `broom::tidy` can tidy a `speedglm` object: https://broom.tidyverse.org/reference/tidy.speedglm.html. In the following examples, `broom::tidy` a `speedglm` object returns some columns as 'fct' rather than 'dbl'. I guess it happens when there are one or more scientific notations in the column. I have tried to change `option(digits = #, scipen = #)` with no luck. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```r
library(broom)
library(speedglm)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading required package: MASS
library(chest)  # get example data (diab_df)

m1 <- glm(Diabetes ~ Sex + Married, family = binomial(), data = diab_df)
tidy(m1) # works fine
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   term          estimate std.error statistic     p.value
#>   <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept) -0.803        0.157  -5.13     0.000000287
#> 2 Sex          0.0958       0.0925  1.04     0.300      
#> 3 Married     -0.0000364    0.0908 -0.000401 1.000

m2 <- speedglm(Diabetes ~ Sex + Married, family = binomial(), data = diab_df)
tidy(m2)  # returns <fct> for values with scintific notation: `estimate` and `p.value`
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   term        estimate     std.error statistic p.value 
#>   <chr>       <fct>            <dbl>     <dbl> <fct>   
#> 1 (Intercept) -8.034e-01      0.157    -5.13   2.87e-07
#> 2 Sex         " 9.578e-02"    0.0925    1.04   3.00e-01
#> 3 Married     -3.640e-05      0.0908   -0.0004 1.00e+00
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This isn't a `broom` issue.  If you examine the model object returned by `speedglm()` in your example both the estimate and p.value are stored as factors.

Comment: Sorry, that should be if you examine the summary object of the model, `str(summary(m2)$coefficients)`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, @H1. I will focus on `speedglm()` for a solution.

Comment: Looking at the summary function for speedglm objects, the issue is that if any of the coefficient types returned has a value < .0001 then scientific formatting is applied which changes the vector to character type (e.g. `format(z$coefficients, scientific = TRUE, digits = 4)`).  The vectors are then passed to a data frame which by default converts strings to factors.  So you can either modify the function to prevent either the scientific conversion or strings becoming factors or, more simply, just convert the factors back to numeric (`as.numeric(as.character(x))`).

Comment: @H1 Great! I think you have pointed to the right direction. For my own work, I will use the latter, and leave the original developers to update (modify) `speedglm`.